# Cannot send Calendar event when setting Organizer

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar, rfc5545

I'm creating an .ics file programmatically in VBScript, which successfully creates the meeting request - no issues here. (RFC 5545)

The problem arises when I try to add an organizer to the file.  For instance, I'm trying to set the organizer to our Release Calendar so that all of our release management staff can manage the event.

If I take out ORGANIZER, it works fine though the event will not be posted to the correct release management calendar.  When I set the ORGANIZER, the meeting request looks like when you open a request that someone else sent you - no Send button, only can Save & Close.  Saving & Closing does not put the event on the ORGANIZER's calendar or any of the attendees' calendars.

Here's the code:

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID: -//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:mailto:ReleaseCalendar@mailserver.com
DTSTAMP:20140620T094745
UID:20140620T094745
DTSTART:20140625T110000
DTEND:20140625T120000
LOCATION:QA
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Test - Test Release for Testing
END:VALARM
CATEGORIES:QA Site
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN='Me':mailto:me@mailserver.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN='Programmer':mailto:Programmer@mailserver.com
SUMMARY:REL QA - Test - Test Release for Testing - Wednesday, June 25, 2014 at 11:00 AM
DESCRIPTION:Test - Test Release for Testing
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<Here's a bunch of HTML that correctly displays>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`

Is there a way to do what I need to do, or is this a hopeless cause?

CLARITY EDIT:  What I need to do is to be able to set the ORGANIZER -and- still be allowed to send the invite.  With ORGANIZER set, there is no Send button.

EDIT:  I've read through RFC 5545 and RFC 6047 and am unable to get around this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The organizer must be yourself for this to work correctly. Without that, you are considered an attendee and attendees are only able to modify a few properties and make a few actions (such as replying).